# Problem with Sketchup_Import- Plugin for blender

Tags: python, animation, add-on

I installed the addon for SketchUp-importer in blender but I still can't enable the addon as it is shown in addon that the plugin is successfully installed but it is blurred-out and I waited for about 2 days to let it self configure properly but still it won't start.
What should I do, please guide me with the issue.

Comment: That's a third-party addon and is not part of Blender so you should ask on the Sketchup forum which seems to be [here](https://forums.sketchup.com/).

Comment: I'm just asking. Is there a reason why you cannot export your Sketchup model as a Collada ,dae file? Blender both imports and exports Collada files.